# What would the claws, teeth, and eyes look like on my species?

Tags: creature-design

I want to understand the shape of the claws, what kind of teeth would they have, or what eyes would they most likely have.
The species is a semi-sapient (like early humans) humanoid in shape and live in birch forests. They are called Keysii. The habitat must have a water source nearby, so they can construct huts, stay hydrated, and have an alternative source of food like salamanders, fish, or turtles. The species is rather gangly, thin, and boney with a long prehensile tail. They blend in with white or black skin dappled in white or black birch markings, their hair will either has the same pattern as their skin, or leaf-like/branch-like hair. A "breed" (kinda like dogs? Idk what to call it) have that hair, but also have clusters of leaf patterns over their upper torso and arms. They have "fake leaves" which are thin, green protrusions of the skin like feathers to better blend in. These Keysii are shorter than the common kinds.
They are omnivorous, mostly eating birds, fish, insects, and fungus. but they also eat moose, porcupines, rabbits, or even the birch trees. They are camouflaged not because they have any natural predators but because prey wouldn't be able to tell when they're there.
The species isn't quite an ambush predator or pursuit predator when land-hunting, they wander the forest when and when they spot prey, they will attempt to stealthily approach until close enough to impale with their claws. If hunting in a water source, they will act like ambush predators and wait for fish, salamander, or turtles to near before striking.
The species doesn't burrow but they do climb trees and make huts (and nests inside the huts) out of the softwood, packed mud, and stone. They don't use tools often but when they do it's for building more complex homes, nurseries, or traps (for catching many fish at a time). They are daytime predators but are able to see well in the shade (not complete nighttime darkness).

edit: This is an old stupid question I seemed to already have an answer for.

Comment: if they just try to stab a moose to death with claws on weak arms, they will be trampled into a pulp. moose occasionally kill bears.

Comment: Hello Ratography, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. This is a very difficult question to answer because it's hard to know the difference between off-topic aesthetics and on-topic purpose. For example, tool-using creatures are unlikely to have claws, which get in the way of gripping things. Predator species tend to have forward-looking eyes, prey species side-facing eyes. Niven's *Pierson's Puppeteers" had eye stalks. Right now the question feels very opinion-based or story-based, which are reasons to close a question. What research have you done? Why can't you decide on the aesthetic yourself?

Answer (score 6):

**They would look like raccoons.**

[image: raccoon in grate]

Because they basically live like raccoons.  They climb trees and eat whatever they can catch, especially in the water.  They would have beady all-purpose eyes like raccoons and medium sharp claws good for climbing and catching and scratching.  Lots and lots of scratching.  And pulling out porcupine quills.

Also your creatures get stuck in grates but they don't rely on the cops; they help each other.  After a lot of laughing.  Once they sober up they help each other.